# Prevent creation of backup org file

Tags: org-mode, init-file, backup

Whenever I create an Org file, a `~` backup file is created. How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Is that file really named `~.org`?

Answer (score 1):

Customize option **`make-backup-files`** to `nil`.

See the Emacs manual, node [Backup](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup.html).

You could find this information yourself by asking Emacs:

1. Open the Emacs manual: **`C-h r`**
2. Consult the index: **`i backup TAB`**.
3. Choose completion candidate **`backup file`**.

That takes you to node `Backup` of the manual, where this option (and more) is described.